Will changing one Switch to primary lose the saved data on the original console?
Question related to trying to travel after buying a second Switch.
I originally bought a Switch when they first came out, rarely played it but during the pandemic I let a now ex use it to play Animal Crossing.  She has put hundreds of hours into it so I let her keep it since I was not using it.
After we split I wanted a Switch to use for post pandemic traveling so I purchased one and just connected my original account thinking nothing of it, but found that the digital games I've since purchased don't work on airplanes as I'm not the primary Switch, the original one is.
If I have her deactivate her Switch so I can make mine the primary account does she lose all her saved data for the physical copy of the only game she plays on her console?
She can keep logged into the account if she is just using it for physical games, I don't care about that, I'm trying to figure out how to play my purchased digital games during a long flight and not have her lose her data at the same time.

I don't think so. Is she using your account to play or did she create a brand new one?

Can you give more details on the accounts?  For instance, I have a My Nintendo account on 2 Switches that has the family plan, my oldest has her own My Nintendo account on one Switch.  The younger kids each had a local account on both.
